# How do I merge the multiple If Else using decode in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The code goes like-

```
If X=x1
then
  select a,b
  from tab
  where zz=yy;

elsif X=x2 or X=x3
then
  select a,b
  from tab
  where zz=yy
  and yy= 123;

elsif X=x4
then
  select a,b
  from tab
  where zz=yy
  and yy= 456;

end if;
```

The code in select is being repeated. How should i merge it?

Comment: Did you specifically want a PL/SQL procedural solution (variables, control flow etc) or is this just about regular DML (writing a query)?

Comment: Is it significant that `zz = yy` appears in all three cases? Also what has `decode` got to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought that a `CASE` statement would be appropriate, but then I noticed that your logic always conditionally selects the same two columns `a` and `b`.  So I think that what you need here is a `WHERE` clause to handle all the cases.

```
SELECT a, b
FROM tab
WHERE (x = 'x1' OR
      ((x = 'x2' OR x = 'x3') AND yy = 123) OR
      (x = 'x4' AND yy = 456)) AND
      zz = yy
```

Comment: This looks logical. Thank you! Will it work the same if I add one more table in FROM clause- tab, tab1. And put the join with one of the OR condition?

Comment: I don't see why a join would necessarily change the logic.

Comment: Right.I will give it a try. But x=x1 OR x=x2 are seperate conditions and are not columns in tab table. How should I validate it then?

Comment: Ok, the query is very huge actually. The scenario is like-we have taken an input from user, it is assigned to a variable 'X'. Now value for that variable is checked which is "x1". So if it matches, we execute select a,b from tab where zz=yy. So basically X is variable which does not exist in table as column,

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL and compose your query from different parts.
For example:

```
-- common part of query
common_query := 'SELECT a, b FROM tab WHERE zz= yy';

-- set additional condition
IF X=x1 THEN add_where := '';
ELSIF X=x2 OR X=x3 THEN add_where := ' AND yy= 123';
ELSIF X=x4 THEN add_where := ' AND yy= 456';
END IF;

-- compose final query
final_query:=  common_query||add_where;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE final_query;
```

Of couse when you use dynamic SQL you can use bind variables and you need to remember about return values.